# Shipping cost not showing on cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping

After adding product to the cart when I check to cart page the shipping rate not showing which was showing earlier. I also checked mage shipping module & it is also enable.

Here is my tax settings

**Tax Classes**

> Tax Class for Shipping : Taxable goods

**calculation setting :**

> Tax Calculation Method Based On : Total
>
> Tax Calculation Based On : Billing Address
>
> Catalog Prices : Excluding tax
>
> Shipping Prices : Including Tax
>
> Apply Customer Tax : After Discount
>
> Apply Discount On Prices : Excluding tax
>
> Apply Tax On : Original
>
> Enable Cross Border Trade : No

**Price Display Setting :**

> Display Product Prices In Catalog : Excluding tax
>
> Display Shipping Prices : Including Tax
>
> shopping cart display setting :
>
> Display Prices : Excluding tax
>
> Display Subtotal : Excluding tax
>
> Display Shipping Amount : Including Tax
>
> Include Tax In Grand Total : No
>
> Display Full Tax Summary : No
>
> Display Zero Tax Subtotal : No

Comment: Your tax settings have nothing to do with the question...

Answer (score 1):

It probably disappeared because your session expired.

Because shipping depends on the quote address (which depends on the customer address), shipping methods cannot be shown/calculated at that stage of the checkout flow yet. That is, unless your session contains an address of course.

Possible ways to deal with this:

- Show the shipping calculator on the cart page (should be enabled by default) so the customer can put in their address and get shipping pricing
- Make an assumption of which country the customer is coming (or use GeoIP) and by using an even observer inject a quote address into the current session so shipping can always be shown

Comment: let me try for this...